# In excel 2003, how do I get queries and pivots to autorefresh?

Tags: excel

I have some sql queries but I'd like it to refresh every hour or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an auto-refresh in the "PivotTable Properties" via the "PivotTable" button on the "PivotTable" toolbar you can change the automatic update property but it won't work to be refreshed "every hour".

What you can try is to refresh when the tab is selected, see this example: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=80